# How can I get SonarQube to analyse test code?

Tags: sonarqube

According to the documentation I've found Sonar will not analyse test code by default.  I found some Jira's that indicate it should be possible but nothing with enough information on how to do it.

It's java code setting under src/test/java.  I use both the eclipse plugin for local analysis and sonar-runner plugin for gradle via a jenkins job on the CI server so ideally the solution would support both those.

Ta,
  Andrew

Answer (score 0):

As of SonarQube 4.2, the only way to have some test code analyzed is to activate rules from "PMD Unit Tests" repository inside your quality profile.

Note that these are rules specific to test code (like the existence of at least one assertion). You can't activate "standard" rules on test code yet. You can vote for the following ticket to extend the scope of source analysis: [SONAR-3748](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-3748)

Comment: Why? Is there any plan to change this?  I'm probably going to have to reevaluate whether we use sonar given this news :-(

Comment: It's always been like this, and everyone is coping with that for now. But this should change sooner or later. FYI, I added the link to a ticket to improve the current situation. Feel free to vote for it to push this feature forward.