# Configure Gradle + Sonar to also analyze unit test classes

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, multi-module

I'm migrating an existing Ant build to Gradle. I'm trying to wire it into our Sonar server, using the `sonar-runner` plugin (with toolVersion 2.4). However, it doesn't analyze (findbugs, checkstyle) the unit tests, which is something that we do need. I'm at a complete loss how to do it, though. I've tried many Sonar configuration properties based on many fruitless Google queries, but none of them work.

I've uploaded a small project to GitHub that demonstrates the issue; [you can find it here](https://github.com/jqno/gradle-sonar-sscce). If I run `gradle sonarRunner` on this, I get nice reports on the `Person` class, but not on the `PersonTest` class.

How can I get FindBugs and Checkstyle warnings on the `PersonTest` class too?

Comment: I believe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545908/how-can-i-get-sonarqube-to-analyse-test-code) is relevant in this context.

Comment: Possibly. But, we use version 4.1.2, and our current Ant build does FindBugs & Checkstyle analysis on unit test code.